# Check the differences of two collections

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 variables: one stores the content of a table and one stores an sql script that checks for all keys in a database.

```
$indexes = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('indexes')->get();

$dbIndexes = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select
        ("
                select 
                    schema_name(t.[schema_id]) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view,
                    substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [columns],
                    case when i.is_primary_key = 1 then 'Primary_key'
                    when i.is_unique = 1 then 'Unique'
                    else 'Not_unique' end as [type],
                    i.[name] as index_name,
                    i.index_id
                    from sys.objects t
                    inner join sys.indexes i
                    on t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
                    cross apply 
                    (
                            select col.[name] + ', '
                            from sys.index_columns ic
                        inner join sys.columns col on ic.[object_id] = col.[object_id] and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        where ic.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
                        and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                        order by col.column_id
                        for xml path ('')
                    ) D (column_names)
                    where t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
                    and index_id > 0
        ");
```

I need to see if what is in the table is also in the sql script, and if not to delete that row. I already tried the "diff" and "diffAssoc" method but shows that all records are different.

```
$diff = $indexes->diffAssoc(get_object_vars(collect($dbIndexes)));
```

Comment: The content of both variable is identical, but both methods finds differences exact the number of rows contained in both variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done is that instead of :

```
$indexes = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('indexes')->get();
```

who returns a collection of object, I have used :

```
$indexes = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->select("select * from indexes");
```

who returns an array. And the comparison of the two is in this way:

```
$indexes = array_map('serialize', $indexes);

$dbIndexes = array_map('serialize', $dbIndexes);

$diff = array_merge(array_diff($indexes,$dbIndexes),array_diff($dbIndexes,$indexes));
```

In this way it checks for differences in both ways. If you will do the check only one way it will show differences.